# How to use DataAnnotations & Regex - c# - ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I am using dataannotations to match fields a user will input for error handling purposes.

Whenever they input an incorrect format, it prints the actual regex and I was wondering if there was a way to remove the "match the following regex" and just print the error message.

Example of my form and the error message displayed:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWKBM.png)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace FoodCart.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,40}$")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Name on Card")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string NameonCard { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Credit Card Number")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required, input valid 16 digit number")]
        [RegularExpression(@" ([0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9]) ([0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9]) ([0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9]) ([0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9][0 - 9])")]
        public string CreditCardNum { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Expiration Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required, input valid expiration date: MM/YY")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9])")]
        public string ExpDate{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CVV")]
        [RegularExpression(@"([0-9][0-9][0-9])")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string cvv { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Total")]
        public decimal YourTotal { get; set; }
        public int UserLinkID { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern you selected is not appropriate. What do you want to do with the pattern?

Answer (score 2):

The validation attributes all come with a default error message that is built into the implementation. For the `RegularExpressionAttribute`, this error message is the following:

> The field {0} must match the regular expression '{1}'.

The placeholder `{0}` will be the display name of the property that is being validated and `{1}` will be the regular expression itself.

There are a few ways to customize this error message, using one of the [properties on the validation attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute?view=netcore-3.1#properties). The simplest way would be to specify the error message directly with the `ErrorMessage` property. Note that you can still refer to the placeholders `{0}` (for the field name) and `{1}` (for the regular expression) if you like:

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z'-\s]{1,40}$", ErrorMessage = "The field {0} is not a valid name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[RegularExpression(@"([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][0-9])",ErrorMessage = "your message")]
```